# Employment Law - Requirements for cover during leave

Tags: united-kingdom, workload, holidays

I have had to cover my leave for 6 years now.  I am a NHS Medical Secretary and having had a conversation with my manager that I will need cover and giving written instructions/information relating to my job for my two week holiday, nothing was done.  Effectively, I have covered my own leave for 6 years and have come back from a well earned rest to a mountain of work.  I find this puts a lot of pressure on me and takes the enjoyment off the holiday to come back to an unmanageable amount of work that has been piling up in my absence.

How should I approach this with my employer in order to avoid finding myself in this situation in the future?

Comment: Talk to your UNISON rep, assuming you are a member. If you're not, well, that's what unions are for.

Comment: Check your contract, check how many hours a week you should be working, check if there is pay for working overtime, and if there isn't, work the hours in your contract.

Comment: Welcome to the site @PrettyShield :) I've taken the step of editing your question - mainly to make the goal a bit clearer and more concrete, and I've edited the title and tags of the question to better illustrate the subject and help the right users find your question.

Comment: What you should not do is work twice as fast until you catch up. Logically you should be x * 6 weeks behind at the moment - x being the number of weeks holiday per year.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere If the employer assigns 52 weeks worth of work per year to Pretty Shield and somehow assumes they will work overtime/ extrahard around their annual leave to cover that, then the employer screwed up and it is not up to the employee to try to fix that. Employees have a legal right to their annual leave and the employer needs to account for that not that the employee.

Answer (score 9):

The employer can't *deny* you (ever) taking leave because there's no cover but there's nothing in employment law saying that your duties need to be performed/covered by someone else while you're on leave. So that's a non-starter.

Yes coming back from a period of leave to a mountain of work that built up in your absence is annoying and frustrating, but it's not something you can eliminate entirely and if you ever did you'd probably have done a pretty good job of proving that the employer doesn't actually need to keep you!

This doesn't mean there's nothing that you can do to make your life easier - the employer should be taking some steps to ensure that at least some of the slack is picked up in your absence and the best avenue for persuading them to be more proactive on that is by pointing out the harms to the organisation that result in your work going completely unattended while you're on holiday. Are deadlines or targets not being met? Are patients complaining? Are other staff left blocked on their work? That sort of thing.

It's human nature to care more about things that affect us directly - and organisations are no different in that regard. So getting them to understand how it's a problem for *them* goes a long way towards motivating them to do something about it!

If, after agreeing what will be done in your absence (and who is responsible for seeing it happens) these things *aren't* done you raise that with your manager, iterate the harms done to the organisation and that then makes it the organisations problem to prevent in future.

But what if they can't or won't do anything about it? That would suggest that such a reluctance is likely endemic to the organisation - which means you probably aren't the only person who has difficulties with this. So what you can do there is identify a colleague with a compatible-enough role to you and essentially agree between you to cover each others holidays, that way you both benefit.

Answer (score 4):

I don't really see a legal issue here. You're going on leave, and your usual work isn't being done while you're away, so when you return there's a backlog. But that's not your problem. If the amount of work that you come back to is unmanageable, that a problem for your manager.

When you get back, the first thing that you should do is to sit down with your manager, look at the backlog, and ask them to prioritise what they want done. You've got 8 hours in your working day, so if there's 12 hours of work that needs doing then your manager either needs to allocate someone else to it, or needs to decide which 4 hours can wait.

And if they complain about some of the work not getting done, then you can point to your written instructions for while you were away (which were ignored), and point to their prioritisation of the work (which you should get in writing).

And as @Phillip Kendall says, if you get any pushback over this then you should be talking to your union rep.